# How to convert a xlsx file to doc table format using php

Tags: php, xls, xlsx, doc

I would like to convert a xlsx file into doc table format. How can I do that ? Is there any api for handling doc files using php ?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a very broad question, I only describe how I'd tackle a request like this:

1. Use [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) to parse your MSExcel xlsx file
2. Use [PHPWord](https://phpword.codeplex.com/) to write your table into a MSWord doc file.